# Conditional preceding values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, gaps-and-islands

My sample data is like this

```
drop 
  table if exists #temp
select 
  * into #temp
from 
  (
    values 
      ('id100', 'status1', 1), 
      ('id100', 'status2', 2), 
      ('id100', 'status1', 3), 
      ('id100', 'status0', 4), 
      ('id100', 'status2', 5), 
      ('id100', 'status2', 6), 
      ('id100', 'status1', 7), 
      ('id100', 'status1', 8), 
      ('id100', 'status2', 9), 
      ('id101', 'status1', 10), 
      ('id101', 'status2', 11)
  ) t(id, status, rowNum)
```

I need TSQL to return immediately preceding rowNum for each id with 'status2' where the status='status1'. I hope the code to return this

| id | status | rowNum | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id100 | status1 | 1 |  |
| id100 | status2 | 2 | 1 |
| id100 | status1 | 3 |  |
| id100 | status0 | 4 |  |
| id100 | status2 | 5 | 3 |
| id100 | status2 | 6 | 3 |
| id100 | status1 | 7 |  |
| id100 | status1 | 8 |  |
| id100 | status2 | 9 | 8 |
| id101 | status1 | 10 |  |
| id101 | status2 | 11 | 10 |

I tried this which did not work

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.status, 
  t1.rowNum, 
  (
    select 
      MIN(t2.rowNum) 
    from 
      #temp t2 
    where 
      t2.id = t1.id 
      and t2.rowNum < t1.rowNum 
      and t1.status = 'status2'
  ) as test 
from 
  #temp t1
```

Comment: check out LAG window function

Comment: Looks like a gaps-and-islands problem

Comment: window max() over(order by) `select *, case when status='status2' then max(case when status='status1' then rowNum end) over(partition by id order by rowNum) end
from #temp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use subquery within a case statement to do so:

Query:

```
  select *, CASE WHEN status='status2' then (select max(rowNum) from #temp tmp 
    where tmp.rowNum<t.rowNum and tmp.status='status1') end value
  from #temp t
order by rowNum
```

Output:

| id | status | rowNum | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id100 | status1 | 1 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 2 | 1 |
| id100 | status1 | 3 | *null* |
| id100 | status0 | 4 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 5 | 3 |
| id100 | status2 | 6 | 3 |
| id100 | status1 | 7 | *null* |
| id100 | status1 | 8 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 9 | 8 |
| id101 | status1 | 10 | *null* |
| id101 | status2 | 11 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QtqK0UVt)

You can also use `last_value()` window function or `lag()` window function instead of subquery:

Query (with last_value()over()):

```
 select *, CASE WHEN status='status2' then 
    (last_value(case when status='status1' then rowNum else null end) ignore nulls over(order by rowNum)) end value
  from #temp t
order by rowNum
```

Output:

| id | status | rowNum | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id100 | status1 | 1 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 2 | 1 |
| id100 | status1 | 3 | *null* |
| id100 | status0 | 4 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 5 | 3 |
| id100 | status2 | 6 | 3 |
| id100 | status1 | 7 | *null* |
| id100 | status1 | 8 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 9 | 8 |
| id101 | status1 | 10 | *null* |
| id101 | status2 | 11 | 10 |

Query (with lag()over()):

```
select *, CASE WHEN status='status2' then 
    (lag(case when status='status1' then rowNum else null end) ignore nulls over(order by rowNum)) end value
  from #temp t
order by rowNum
```

Output:

| id | status | rowNum | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id100 | status1 | 1 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 2 | 1 |
| id100 | status1 | 3 | *null* |
| id100 | status0 | 4 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 5 | 3 |
| id100 | status2 | 6 | 3 |
| id100 | status1 | 7 | *null* |
| id100 | status1 | 8 | *null* |
| id100 | status2 | 9 | 8 |
| id101 | status1 | 10 | *null* |
| id101 | status2 | 11 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p0-4ko3S)

Comment: Wow, Microsoft finally added support for `ignore nulls` in window functions, that’s big news! Thanks for demonstrating it.

Comment: Note that `ignore nulls` is not even mentionned in [the documentation of `lag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)… although I can see it works in your fiddle. It is documented in `last_value` though.

Comment: You are most welcom @GMB. I didn't know it's not in the documentation of lag. It should be there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky enough to be running SQL Server 2022, we can just use `last_value()` with the `ignore nulls` option - as demonstrated in [the answer of Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76066907/10676716).

In earlier versions, where the option is not available, one approach uses some gaps-and-island technique here.

```
select t.*,
    case when status = 'status2' then
        max(case when status = 'status1' then rownum end) 
            over(partition by id, grp order by rownum) 
    end value
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when status = 'status1' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by id order by rownum) grp
    from #temp t
) t
order by id, rownum
```

Islands start with a status 2; we can identify them with a conditional window sum; then, every time a status 2 is met within the island, we retrieve the row num of the corresponding status 1.

An alternative is `apply`- although it might be less efficient, since it requires re-opening the table in the subquery:

```
select t.*, x.*
from #temp t
outer apply (
    select max(x.rownum) value
    from #temp x
    where x.id = t.id
      and x.rownum < t.rownum
      and x.status = 'status1'
      and t.status = 'status2'
) x
order by t.id, t.rownum
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple correlated query:

```
select *,
  case when status = 'status2' then (
    select top(1) Cast(rowNum as varchar(2))
    from #temp t2 
    where t2.id = t.id and t2.status= 'status1' and t2.rowNum < t.rowNum
    order by rowNum desc
  )
  else '' end [Value]
from #temp t
order by id, rowNum;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OHsezQiq)

This simply follow the specification to select the first qualifying row based on the predicates for Status.

In order to meet your desired results it's cast to type varchar, if you are happy with `NULL` instead you can omit the cast and the `else` part.

This would be optimally helped with a clustered index on Id and rowNum.